# How to add a parent and a child to this Tree class

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I'm working on an ID3 Algorithm, one of the requirements is that I add the parent and child to this class without modifying it. I'm not sure the best way to go about it? Does anyone have any ideas?

```
class Tree {

    Tree[] children;
    int value;

    public Tree(Tree[] ch, int val) {
        value = val;
        children = ch;
    } // constructor

    public String toString() {
        return toString("");
    } // toString()

    String toString(String indent) {
        if (children != null) {
            String s = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
                s += indent + data[0][value] + "=" + strings[value][i] + "\n" + children[i].toString(indent + '\t');
            return s;
        } else
            return indent + "Class: " + strings[attributes - 1][value] + "\n";
    } // toString(String)

} // inner class Tree
```

Comment: Is that what you're asking? `Tree child = new Tree(null, 1); Tree parent = new Tree(new Tree[] {child}, 2);`. What do you mean by "add the parent and child to this class"?

Comment: Yes thanks, sorry I was slightly confused but this works. Thanks.